# X primary threatens Y = Y is most vulnerable to X?

Tags: comparison

There is a question in one of the LSATs which takes the following two sentences as interchangeable:

(1) Disturbed habitats are most vulnerable to new arrivals.

(2) New species primarily threatens disturbed areas.

I am very confused because (1) only states the vulnerability of disturbed habitats; I can't see how influential new species are.
On the other hand, (2) only talks about new species' impact but nothing about the vulnerability of the habitats.

I would really appreciate your help if you could help explain how those two sentences can be interchangeable.

Thank you very much,
Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended meaning is that disturbing a habitat makes it more vulnerable to new species. The first sentence would be better with "**the** most vulnerable to new arrivals", which would make the comparison to stable (undisturbed) habitats clearer.

The second sentence should have "threaten", to agree with the plural subject "species". It compares the impact of (new species = new arrivals) on disturbed, compared to stable (undisturbed) areas.